# Disable discovery of my environments in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

In Microsoft Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement/ Sales, is it possible that I can disable/ block the global discovery service from returning information about any of the environments in my organization?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/discover-url-organization-web-api

For some internal security reason, I want to disable the global discovery from listing our internal Dynamics 365 environments.

Comment: Visibility is restricted to environments your users have access to - they are not visible publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot turn off Global discovery.  It is however, only accessible via User Auth and results are filtered by that user.  The calling user must have an account in an environment for that environment to be shown.

As Filburt comments, you can restrict environments that are shown to users by using security groups associated with the environments to limit access.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/control-user-access#associate-a-security-group-with-a-dataverse-environment